# Horizontally aligned images with equal width and static margins?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive image gallery for a project I'm working on and I've run into some trouble. For the mobile version of the site, I want each row of the gallery to have three thumbnails of equal width and a 15px gutter. I can get the images to take up equal space by making them each 33.33% wide, of course, but the 15px right margin I attempted to apply to the first two images in the row pushed the third off. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a wrapper? You can use a pseudo class to select the last one. .wrapper img:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

Comment: The problem is that the first two margins push the third image off. I've tried using calc(33.33% - 15px) to account for the margins, but the calculation being left off of the last image makes it both wider and taller. I'm a little rusty right now, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browsers you need to support you could use:

```
width: calc(33% - 15px);
margin-right: 15px;
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

That should fix the issue of the last image rolling to the next row, but without any sample code, that's not easy to prove. Could you provide a fiddle or codepen?

---

EDIT: After Codepen.io was shared

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mkjzd

So when I got the code I noticed that last child and not first child was confused, and that the figure margins were not being overridden. After fixing both those issues, I put a margin right on the first two figures in the row and set the width with calc( 33.333% - 10px ) (why 10 is explained in comments on the code. This fixed the issue.

Comment: I actually commented about this right as I received this answer. While calc does do the job correctly for the first two images, the third image remains a problem. If I leave the calc, the image doesn't properly align with the right edge of the screen; however, if I remove the calc the image is too large. I'll throw the code up somewhere in a second if it helps.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle or codepen.io? Without the rest of your code there isn't much I can do but guess.

Comment: This is the markup and CSS for the gallery. I'm testing with my browser width below 500px; I know it looks awful at any larger widths. http://codepen.io/jamjnsn/pen/kcrum/

Comment: I switched it from .sass to .scss and it seems to work.

Comment: Oh jeeze, I apparently can't even do simple math now. Thanks so much for this!